# Bug of OnBackPressedDispatcher in androidx preference

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-preferences

There are chain `MainFragment` > `SettingsFragment` > `SubSettingsFragment`:

- from `MainFragment` to `SettingsFragment` via [NavigationController](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started)

```kotlin
navController.navigate(MainFragment.toSettingsFragment())
```

- from `Settings` to `SubSettingsFragment` via [PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat)

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Preference
        android:fragment=".SubSettingsFragment"
        app:summary="@string/pref_header_summary_permission"
        app:title="@string/pref_title_permission" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When we located at `SubSettingsFragment` and press back button, appears `MainFragment`. `SettingsFragment` skipped.

`PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat` has `onBackPressedCallback` handle accoding [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:preference/preference/src/main/java/androidx/preference/PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat.kt?q=file:androidx%2Fpreference%2FPreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat.kt%20class:androidx.preference.PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat). But for some reason don't work.

Can we connect backstack of `NavController` to `PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat`?

### Update 1

I found why `onBackPressedCallback` don't work. In official source code in `onViewCreated`, dispatcher from context is null. That's why `addCallback` isn't run.

```kotlin
    @CallSuper
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        onBackPressedCallback = InnerOnBackPressedCallback(this)
        slidingPaneLayout.doOnLayout {
            onBackPressedCallback!!.isEnabled =
                slidingPaneLayout.isSlideable && slidingPaneLayout.isOpen
        }
        childFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            onBackPressedCallback!!.isEnabled = childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0
        }

        // this owner is null
        val onBackPressedDispatcherOwner = requireContext() as? OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner
        onBackPressedDispatcherOwner?.let {
            it.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
                viewLifecycleOwner,
                onBackPressedCallback!!
            )
        }
    }
```

I create custom `PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat` where change `requireContext()` to `requireActivity()` and it's works. Back pressed from `SubSettingsFragment` pop to `SettingsFragment`.

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
    viewLifecycleOwner,
    onBackPressedCallback!!
)
```

Do you know why `requireContext() as? OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner` is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `onViewCreated()` of official `PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat`. Fixed by Google for future release (see [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/286899046)).

```kotlin
// this owner is null when we use Hilt annotation - AndroidEntryPoint 
val onBackPressedDispatcherOwner = requireContext() as? OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner
onBackPressedDispatcherOwner?.let {
    it.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        onBackPressedCallback!!
    )
}
```